# Add a new day column

Tags: r

Having this data:

```
dates
1990-02-02 01:00:00
1990-02-02 02:00:00
1990-02-03 01:00:00
1990-02-03 02:00:00
1990-02-04 01:00:00
1990-02-04 02:00:00
```

Could I create a column, in which every row has the number of day like this?

```
number dates
1      1990-02-02 01:00:00
1      1990-02-02 02:00:00
2      1990-02-03 01:00:00
2      1990-02-03 02:00:00
3      1990-02-04 01:00:00
3      1990-02-04 02:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

The rank function should do what you need but consult the documentation for it as there's not an easily reproducible exampe for me to play with

```
temp <- data.frame(dates = c('1990-02-02 01:00:00',
                             '1990-02-02 02:00:00',
                             '1990-02-03 01:00:00',
                             '1990-02-03 02:00:00',
                             '1990-02-04 01:00:00',
                             '1990-02-04 02:00:00',
                             '1990-02-04 03:00:00'))
temp$datesonly<-as.Date(temp$dates)
temp2<-data.frame(dates=unique(temp$datesonly),ranks=rank(unique(temp$datesonly),ties.method="first"))
temp<-merge(temp,temp2,by.x="datesonly",by.y="dates")
```

Comment: I think you mean `as.Date` (upper case `D`)? But I'm not sure that this approach would work anyway.

Comment: cheers for the heads up! I'm not sure based on what other people put, but the example does indicate that the days should be chronologically given a rank as opposed the day of the month - I'm still relatively new to R myself so it'll be interesting to see what does work if a rank doesn't

Comment: But with `rank`, and `ties.method = "first"`, you're just going to get a series from 1 to the number of rows of your data. Try it with my sample data to see what I mean.

Comment: +1 for persisting through with edits based on the comments! `unique` is what you were looking for with `rank`, though at that point `ties.method` doesn't make sense :)  One advantage of `merge` is that the data do not need to be sorted first.

Comment: In case you're interested in alternatives, I've just posted another as an edit to my original answer.

Answer (score 2):

This solution assumes that the dates are listed in chronological order (or are at least sorted by day) and that the dates are actually formatted as date time objects.

```
temp <- data.frame(dates = c('1990-02-02 01:00:00',
                             '1990-02-02 02:00:00',
                             '1990-02-03 01:00:00',
                             '1990-02-03 02:00:00',
                             '1990-02-04 01:00:00',
                             '1990-02-04 02:00:00',
                             '1990-02-04 03:00:00'))
temp$dates <- as.POSIXct(temp$dates, tz = "GMT")
x <- table(as.Date(temp$dates))
temp$number <- rep(seq_along(x), x)
temp
#                 dates number
# 1 1990-02-02 01:00:00      1
# 2 1990-02-02 02:00:00      1
# 3 1990-02-03 01:00:00      2
# 4 1990-02-03 02:00:00      2
# 5 1990-02-04 01:00:00      3
# 6 1990-02-04 02:00:00      3
# 7 1990-02-04 03:00:00      3
```

The basic idea is to just strip the time out (using `as.Date`) and tabulate the frequency of each day. You can then use `rep` on that output to create your "number" variable.

---

*Slap forehead and post a simpler solution*

Just use `factor` on `as.Date`. This would work even on a `data.frame` where the data are not ordered:

```
temp <- data.frame(dates = c('1990-02-02 01:00:00',
                             '1990-02-02 02:00:00',
                             '1990-02-03 01:00:00',
                             '1990-02-03 02:00:00',
                             '1990-02-04 01:00:00',
                             '1990-02-04 02:00:00',
                             '1990-02-04 03:00:00'))
temp$dates <- as.POSIXct(temp$dates, tz = "GMT")
within(temp, {
  counts <- as.numeric(factor(as.Date(dates)))
})
#                 dates counts
# 1 1990-02-02 01:00:00      1
# 2 1990-02-02 02:00:00      1
# 3 1990-02-03 01:00:00      2
# 4 1990-02-03 02:00:00      2
# 5 1990-02-04 01:00:00      3
# 6 1990-02-04 02:00:00      3
# 7 1990-02-04 03:00:00      3
```

Answer (score 0):

Tries with this...

```
- library(lubridate)

date <- c("1990-02-02 01:00:00",
"1990-02-02 02:00:00",
"1990-02-03 01:00:00",
"1990-02-03 02:00:00",
"1990-02-04 01:00:00",
"1990-02-04 02:00:00")

number <- day(date)
cbind.data.frame(number,date)
```